# Random pages printing with curl command

Tags: macos, printing

I need some help with this...
My printer (hp inkjet) will randomly print 3 pages with just a header that includes the curl command (see photo) since this is a major waste of paper, how do I get this to stop?

I don’t have any server type apps installed so I don’t know what’s going on.

[image]

Is someone getting in to my printer or how would I know if my Mac is sending these to the printer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a netgear router?

[Look here](https://community.netgear.com/t5/NETGEAR-Armor/bd-p/en-home-armor) and search for “printer”. It looks like it could be something to do with vulnerability scanning in your router.

Suggestions are:

- turn off the vulnerability scan in the router
- turn off the web services on the printer

Comment: Thanks, that looks like the solution.

Comment: @ewmjr excellent, for clarity which solution worked for you?

Comment: After reading the NETGEAR site I’ll need to update firmware. 
I also needed to turn of the security scan since that’s what’s causing the problem. 
So far I haven’t updated the firmware since I don’t want to go offline for an unknown length of time (I’ll probably mess it up once or twice) now that we’re at home all the time.